# Ошибка ErrorException in LoginController.php line 29: Undefined index: response

Tags: php, авторизация

Помогите решить

```
in LoginController.php line 29
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: response', '/var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php', '29', array('r' => object(Request), 'client_id' => '7369650', 'client_secret' => '41wyzyJs8WUz3GjCnssx', 'redirect_uri' => 'cccard.ru', 'obj' => object(stdClass), 'info' => array('error' => array('error_code' => '8', 'error_msg' => 'Invalid request: versions below 5.00 are deprecated. Version param should be passed as "v". "version" param is invalid and not supported. For more information go to https://vk.com/dev/version_update_2.0', 'request_params' => array(array('key' => 'user_ids', 'value' => ''), array('key' => 'fields', 'value' => 'photo_200'), array('key' => 'v', 'value' => 'V'), array('key' => 'method', 'value' => 'users.get'), array('key' => 'oauth', 'value' => '1')))))) in LoginController.php line 29
3.at LoginController->vklogin(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LoginController), 'vklogin'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('vklogin', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(LoginController), object(Route), 'vklogin') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(LoginController), object(Route), object(Request), 'vklogin') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController', 'vklogin') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Вот сам код:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function vklogin(Request $r)
    {
        $client_id = '7369650';
        $client_secret = '41wyzyJs8WUz3GjCnssx';
        $redirect_uri = 'cccard.ru';

        if (!is_null($r->code)) {

            $obj = json_decode($this->curl('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=' . $client_id . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&redirect_uri=http://' . $redirect_uri . '/login&code=' . $r->code));

            if (isset($obj->access_token)) {

                $info = json_decode($this->curl('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids&fields=photo_200&access_token=' . $obj->access_token . '&v=V'), true);



  $user = User::where('login2', $info['response'][0]['uid'])->first();
                if($user == NULL) {
                if(array_key_exists('photo_200', $info['response'][0])){
                      $photo = $info['response'][0]['photo_200'];
                  }else{
                    $photo = 'http://vk.com/images/camera_200.png';
                  }
                    $user = User::create([
                        'username' => $info['response'][0]['last_name'] . ' ' . $info['response'][0]['first_name'],
                        'avatar' => $photo,
                        'login' => 'id'.$info['response'][0]['uid'],
                        'login2' => $info['response'][0]['uid'],
                        'ref_code' => $this->generate(),
                        'nick' => $this->generate_name()
                    ]);
                } else {
                  if(array_key_exists('photo_200', $info['response'][0])){
                      $photo = $info['response'][0]['photo_200'];
                  }else{
                    $photo = 'http://vk.com/images/camera_200.png';
                  }
                    $user->username = $info['response'][0]['last_name'] . ' ' . $info['response'][0]['first_name'];
                    $user->avatar = $photo;
                    $user->login = 'id'.$info['response'][0]['uid'];
                    $user->login2 = $info['response'][0]['uid'];
                    $user->save();
                }

                Auth::login($user, true);
                return redirect('/');

            }

        } else {
            return redirect('https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=' . $client_id . '&display=page&redirect_uri=http://' . $redirect_uri . '/login&scope=friends,photos,status,offline,&response_type=code&v=5.53');
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function curl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }

    public function generate_name()
    {
        $length = 8;
        $chars = 'abdefhiknrstyzABDEFGHKNQRSTYZ23456789';
        $numChars = strlen($chars);
        $string = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
        }
        return $string;
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        $length = 13;
        $chars = 'abdefhiknrstyzABDEFGHKNQRSTYZ23456789';
        $numChars = strlen($chars);
        $string = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
        }
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: а чё тут решать то? Переменная $info не содержит ключа response

Comment: А как это тогда исправить?

Comment: ну проверьте что находится в переменной